# Female=gender counterpart?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Population:

- male is 100
- female is 90

> The population of males is higher than their "**gender** **counterpart**"

Or

> The population of males is higher than their "**female** **counterpart**"

Let's say you are trying your best to find the synonym of "**female**", so you used the bold words above.
Which of the two is the correct English words that is equivalent to the word *female*?

Answer (score 24):

I believe neither of those two sentences uses the word "counterpart" correctly. The word "counterpart" does not refer to opposites. Let me give you an example. "The generals met with their counterparts from the enemy army to discuss terms of surrender." In other words, the generals are meeting with the enemy generals. They are alike instead of opposite. They are doing the same kind of job. Here's another example. The President of the United States, Donald Trump, met with his counterpart, the Chancellor of Germany, Angela Merkel. They both hold a similar job, so they are counterparts, even though one is male and one is female.

It would be more correct to write:

The male population is higher than that of the opposite gender.

Or just:

The male population is higher than the female population.

Comment: Oh that's another synonym. Excellent. But, is there any other way to use counterpart in my sentence?

Comment: John:  the answer is "No, there isn't".

Comment: @JohnArvin "Equivalent" would be acceptable though. "Counterpart" is too specifically an individual though.

Comment: I don't see the issue with "counterpart from the other gender" in the way you describe in this answer, any more than there's issue with "counterpart from the enemy army". Wether the group is "generals" or "population", counterpart as a word works the same, as far as I can see.

Comment: Hmm, but are not males and females rather counterparts (complements) than opposites ? Like the counterpart to black is non-black, but the opposite is white.

Comment: @Poutnik No, I would not use "counterpart" in any context where it does not imply some essential similarity. It can in some cases be used of things that are both comparable and complementary, like male and female, but sounds wrong to me for black and non-black (whether in the literal color or racial sense).

Comment: Ok, the colours may not be a good example. But M and F seems definitely to me rather complements than counterparts, and rather counterparts than opposites. But I am not a native, so I have no weight here. :-)

Answer (score 14):

One of the definitions of "counterpart" on www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary says:

> Something that completes : COMPLEMENT
>   *"The lead actress and her male counterpart"*

**Gender counterpart** would *generally* mean ***the other gender***. So if it's for males, the counterpart would be understood to be female and vice versa. (It works here because there are only two genders. If talking about more, this could create confusion.)

**Female counterpart** would *specifically* mean ***the females***.

Comment: As a native British English speaker, I would understand what both sentences are trying to convey, but I would regard both as wrong.  (They are neither anything that a native speaker would ever say.)

Comment: The example here is misleading. There's a lead actress, presumably more actors, and one of the actors is a (male) lead actor.  This is a normal playwriting style, where a performance has two main characters so you can write a dialog. So the specific setup with a counterpart is very much intentional. If the roles were not written as counterparts, they wouldn't be having the dialog, and the audience wouldn't be able to follow what's happening.

Comment: Actually, as a native speaker, I _might_ say "than their female counterparts", but only if my intention were more style than abject clarity (which, let's face it, isn't unusual :D) Certainly it sounds natural enough to me, if not particularly common in this context

Answer (score 8):

If you're really desperate not to use *female* or *women*, you could use the everyday terms ***opposite sex*** or (less commonly) ***opposite gender***. If you really want to sound fancy - which is what it sounds like you're trying to do - you could say ***gender complement***, but **this is not a widely used term** (though it's not completely unattested). It just makes sense [in terms of what *complement* means](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/complement)<sup>1</sup>, at least if you take a heteronormative view (that is to say, the idea that a man and a woman 'complete' one another). *Counterpart* isn't a natural thing to use in this situation at all.

Really, you're better off with a simpler and less obscure term.

---

<sup>1</sup>: Interestingly, the dictionary suggests that *counterpart* and *complement* are synonyms, but in this sense of *completion*, *complement* is what gets used. If you're composing a meal and working out what goes well with what else, you are looking for good *complements* - things that *complement* each other well, using it as a verb.

Comment: I think it might also be related to the mathematical meaning of "complement", e.g. "complementary angles".

Comment: @nick012000 Yes, or complement sets, or complement subgroups, etc etc. All about "making complete" or "things that are not X" or similar. There's a reason mathematics uses that word.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to maintain your use of *counterpart*, you can do so by using *male* and *female* as adjectives:

> The ***male*** *population* is higher than its ***female*** *counterpart*.

Answer (score 2):

> The population of males is higher than their gender counterpart.

I wouldn't say that this is flat out wrong, but it makes the reader stop and think to understand what is being said, and it feels both akward and pretentious. I would advise against using this.

> The population of males is higher than their female counterpart.

This is clearer, but "counterpart" seems to serve no useful purpose except to increase the average word length and falsely suggest greater precision.

> The population of males is larger than the population of females.

This is clearer and more accurate. If it is OK to write "males", then it should be OK to write 'females". The parallelism in form emphasizes the parallelism in meaning.  "Higher" not as good a way to describe the increase in population numbers as "larger".

By the way, in the example sentences in the question, either "their" should be changed to "its" treating a "population" as a single thing, or else "counterpart" should be "counterparts", treatign it as a collection of people. I would favor the 'its' form.

Comment: Even better still: _The male population is higher than the female population_. (That "population of males" bit just [isn't how the word is generally used](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=male+population%2Cpopulation+of+males%2Cfemale+population%2Cpopulation+of+females&year_start=1970&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3).)

Comment: @J.R. Even better: *The male population is larger than the female population.*

Comment: That could be ambiguous; it could be interpreted as saying that males are taller and heavier than females. But that's a different question altogether. :-)

Comment: @J.R. "Higher" could equally be interpreted as "taller". When modifying "population" "larger" seems to default to meaning "more numerous " unless context indicates otherwise.

Comment: @J.R. You would think written communication would be ambiguity free, but I see more and more it isn't.  I just had the experience of writing a message to my doctor and taking pains to give him the facts, and it was still misunderstood.